# Encountered unsupported property AutoScalingReplacingUpdate

Tags: aws-cloudformation

`Encountered unsupported property AutoScalingReplacingUpdate` error appears when trying to launch a stack that contains the following `AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup`:

```
   myAutoScalingGroup:
    Type: 'AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup'
    CreationPolicy:
      AutoScalingReplacingUpdate:
        WillReplace: true
    Properties:
      HealthCheckType: ELB
      HealthCheckGracePeriod: 300
      AvailabilityZones:
        - eu-west-1a
        - eu-west-1b
        - eu-west-1c
      VPCZoneIdentifier:
        - 'Fn::ImportValue': !Sub '${vpcId1}'
        - 'Fn::ImportValue': !Sub '${vpcId2}'
        - 'Fn::ImportValue': !Sub '${vpcId3}'
      MetricsCollection:
        - Granularity: 1Minute
          Metrics:
            - GroupMinSize
            - GroupMaxSize
            - GroupInServiceInstances
            - GroupPendingInstances
            - GroupTerminatingInstances
      MinSize: !Ref AutoScalingGroupWSMinSize
      MaxSize: !Ref AutoScalingGroupWSMaxSize
      LaunchConfigurationName: !Ref myLaunchConfig
      TargetGroupARNs:
        - !Ref myTargetGroup
```

I have found a (undesired) workaround for this but i really don't want to rely on it. The work around is the following:

1. comment out

   ```
   CreationPolicy:
     AutoScalingReplacingUpdate:
       WillReplace: true
   ```
2. launch the template
3. update the successfully launched stack by uncommenting the above
   lines

This is bad and i don't want to do it, since my goal is to automate my infrastructure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The atribute CreationPolicy do not have the AutoScalingReplacingUpdate property

```
CreationPolicy:
  AutoScalingCreationPolicy:
    MinSuccessfulInstancesPercent: Integer
  ResourceSignal: 
    Count: Integer
    Timeout: String
```

The attribute UpdatePolicy is the one that does have the property AutoScalingReplacingUpdate:

```
UpdatePolicy:
  AutoScalingReplacingUpdate:
  WillReplace: Boolean
```